# C# Dll import unsigned char *

Tags: c#, dll, import

I'm trying to call a Dll function:

```
ISO15693_Inventory(unsigned short icdev, unsigned char *pData, unsigned char *pLen)

Parameter:
icdev:  [IN]  Communication device identifier
pData:  [OUT] Response data from tag, 1 byte DSFID + 8 bytes UID
pLen:   [OUT] Length of response data
```

Imported as:

```
[DllImport("MasterRD.dll")]
static extern int ISO15693_Inventorys(short icdev, IntPtr pData, ref byte pLen);
```

But i can´t get it to work. I'm doing something wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you seeing an error message?

Comment: `i can't get it to work` tells us absolutely nothing about the problem you are encountering. BE MORE SPECIFIC.

Comment: Returning error code "20 Request failure"

Comment: int ISO15693_Inventory(ushort dev, byte[] data, ref byte len)